# Where is the history in IE10 Modern UI?

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10

Apparently there isn't a way to peruse the browsing history in IE10 while in Modern UI. How does one access it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open Internet Explorer in desktop mode, the browser history syncs between the two browsers.

Comment: I wonder if Windows RT has IE10 desktop

Comment: WinRT does indeed have a desktop IE10 available.

Comment: nice! Do you know if flash is available too? (I saw flash updates coming from Windows Update on x86)

Comment: Yes, it's available. See [Does Internet Explorer 10 on Windows RT support Flash for all websites?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710431/does-internet-explorer-10-on-windows-rt-support-flash-for-all-websites)